# Approach to create UI Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, extjs

I am new to front end design and would like to know what are the things i need to work on to create a Framework for User Interface. Like if I want to make all the data fields look like same in all the 300 pages i am working on, i would create a class for that field.

Things I know are

Need to Identify what are the fields in those 300 pages,
Validations and messages and their display.
Read up on Javascript frameworks
Worry about Cross browser functionality/display.

What are the other general stuff and also technologies I should be adding to my list.

Thanks,
SixthString

EDIT: I am looking for an answer more like "follow these patterns/concepts/checklists
 when working with 300 pages" so that i would cover most of the stuff and dont have to go through individual pages to change anything. Please help me here as I may be confusing, i would update my question better from your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a framework rather than create one. A framework such as **Java Server Faces** (JSF) will provide you with tags you can use for all standard UI widgets. Generally it's better to use tried and tested components instead of writing your own so that all the hard work of cross-browser compatibility is taken care of. It also helps you separate the funcionality from the presentation style. JSF also provides easy ways to implement validation.

There can a steep learning curve using any web framework for the first time so you're best to start off with a simple app and gradually add complexity.

**Edit**: you've said you've already got a spring back-end. Well JSF can be used along with spring (and in my experience they work well) but you may also want to just use the [spring form tags](http://jroller.com/habuma/entry/spring_form_tags). Either way you'll want to learn about jsp pages and tags.

If you have sets of common form/page elements you want to re-use across pages you can extract them to their own files and include these in multiple pages. You can also write your own custom tags if you need something not covered by the included ones.

Comment: +1 - you have to know what doesn't exist in the tools that are already available before you go and make your own :) Besides, if you say "Knowledgable in SomeUnknownFramework" your resume doesn't mean as much as say, "Knowledgable in YUI, jQuery..." etc. (I just pulled those out of my *hat* they might not be what you're looking for, but the point is still there)

Comment: ok. thanks for the info about JSF. I am more inclined to do stuff with HTML, CSS and ExtJS as these are the only options for me now.

Comment: @SixthString If you are not going to be using Java you shouldn't tag the question with it. How are you intending to store the data entered in your forms?

Comment: @Alb Sorry about the tagging, I am working on a proprietary tool built on Spring framework, so i dont have to worry about data storage and all, just need to worry about how the forms are displayed.

Comment: @SixthString Ah didn't know you were already using spring, I've edited my comment to take this into account.

Comment: @Thanks ALB i started looking in to JSF already, do you have anyother sugessions  for a HTML CSS EXTJS combination users? Thanks.